# Eloquent orWhere() is not working with previous where() methods as expected

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-clause, laravel-7

I'm working on a Friend Request Route.

Expected my code like following to work properly

```
$friends=[];
    foreach (auth()->user()->friends as $friend)
    $friends[]=$friend->id;

    $people = User::query()
    ->where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $friends)
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
    ->get();
```

But this code is working as

`where ( 'id'!=auth()->user()->id and 'id' not in [...] and 'name' like '$name' ) or 'email' like '$email'`

I expected this to work as

`where 'id'!=auth()->user()->id and 'id' not in [...] and ('name' like '$name' or 'email' like '$email')`

Than I changed my code to:

```
$friends=[];
    foreach (auth()->user()->friends as $friend)
    $friends[]=$friend->id;

    $people = User::query()
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
    ->where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $friends)
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
    ->where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $friends)
    ->get();
```

This is working for me but i do not think it proper.
Kindly Guide.

Comment: I think your friend array is not proper try to `dd` the friends array and post the response here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use query for this.

It's something like this :

For more information, you can check this [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)

```
    $people = User::query()
    ->where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $friends)
    ->where(function ($query) {
      $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
    })->get();
```

Comment: I didnt try the request, it's only the concept to use.

Answer (score 2):

You may use "Parameter Grouping" like this:

```php
$people = User::query()
    ->where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $friends)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%")
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$request->search%");
    })
    ->get();
```

> As you can see, passing a `Closure` into the `where` method instructs the query builder to begin a constraint group. The `Closure` will receive a query builder instance which you can use to set the constraints that should be contained within the parenthesis group.

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping) for more info.